# lighttpd 1.4.46+ serve specific file based on $HTTP["useragent"]

Tags: shell, lighttpd, perl, useragent

I have a lighttpd server version 1.4.46+ on Linux which serves **file1.xml** and **file2.xml** from **htdocs** directory as is. There are clients that request these files, each of those send a **User-Agent** header to the server, which have format **MyApp 12345** where **12345** is the client version.

What I need to do is to parse the version number **12345** and serve either **file1.xml** or **file2.xml**, depending on client version number. **file1.xml** needs to be served to clients with version number below **11255** and **file2.xml** needs to be served to clients with version number **11255** and above, and reverse.

What is the easiest way to do this? Preferably to *avoid redirects*, and preferably to *avoid shell or Perl scripts* involved, if possible. Avoiding redirects is at *highest priority*, while using a script is at *lower priority*.

Any lighttpd gurus around to help me out please?

I have tried Perl style regular expression match (=~) on **$HTTP["useragent"]** and setting conditional **server.document-root** to **server_root + "/htdocs/file1"** or **"/htdocs/file2"** that include both files, but failed.

I wanted to try **include_shell**, but not sure how to pass arguments to the script that could handle the version number and possibly write an include configuration file based on results. I could possibly add if-conditions for version numbers **1-11254** to serve **file1.xml** but that list of conditions would become very huge, which looks wrong.

Comment: GG Better here ;)

Comment: @GillesQuénot thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lighttpd [mod_magnet](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_magnet) and a few lines of custom lua code.

```
local r = lighty.r
if r.req_attr["physical.path"] == "/path/to/htdocs/file.xml" then
  local ver = string.match(r.req_header["User-Agent"], "MyApp (%d+)")
  local path = string.sub(r.req_attr["physical.path"], 1, -4)   -- remove '.xml'
  if ver and ver > 12345 then
    r.req_attr["physical.path] = path .. "2.xml"
  else
    r.req_attr["physical.path] = path .. "1.xml"
  end
  r.resp_header["Vary"] = "User-Agent"
end
return 0
```

The above is untested and for lighttpd 1.4.60 or later.  The current version of lighttpd is lighttpd 1.4.69.  If you're running lighttpd 1.4.46, it is likely that your systems are poorly maintained and very out-of-date, but you can find info on the older lighttpd mod_magnet interfaces on the same doc: lighttpd [mod_magnet](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_magnet)